# Hive Alter table column size in VARCHAR

Tags: datatable, hive, size, varchar, hiveddl

I am pretty new in Hive and I have created a table below few months ago

```
create table TableName 
(
    EntityRelationship varchar(20), 
    EntityID varchar(50), 
    EntityName varchar(50), 

    CLUSTERED BY (EntityID) INTO 60 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC
)
```

However, now I have realized `EntityName Varchar(50)` is not enough it needs to be `Varchar(250)`. I found alter table codes but all of them are not changing the size of the column but change types and names.

Also I can not DROP the table as it already have lots of data and that means I have to reload past months daily.

What I want the end table to be described like below

```
create table TableName 
( 
    EntityRelationship varchar(20), 
    EntityID varchar(50), 
    EntityName varchar(250), 
    CLUSTERED BY (EntityID) INTO 60 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC
)
```

Is there away I can alter this existing table going forward to `EntityName varchar(250)` without dropping the table? Appreciate your time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN EntityName EntityName  varchar(250);
```

Read more details: [Change Column Name/Type/Position/Comment](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment)

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin code works perfect. saved lot of work form me.

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE varchar(250);

may this help

Answer (score 0):

@YJG if your alter statement is not effecting the column size, you may have no other chance than to build a new table of the format you want, INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable.  Then rename oldTable to backupTable, and rename newTable to oldTable.   This method of moving data through a staging table is sometimes necessary when changing the original table schema is not working.